# cannot read property of 'map' undefined - typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a simple app with react using typescript, its my first time using typescript with context api and to this level so I'm having issues I don't quite understand. my main issues is my `.map` doesn't seem to me working and for some reason and gives me the error I provided in the title and when I click the `Add catergory` button in the `Main.tsx` file nothing seems to work there either? Any ideas? I've created a sandbox below.

Any help would be appreciated please, thank you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-violet-j1gjz?file=/src/components/CategoryList.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Your error simply mean that "state" is undefined.

```
const { state } = useContext(Store) || [];
```

Mean that you want to extract the property named state from the result of "useContext(Store) || [];"

In the case where you have an empty Array it make no sens, you array will not have a property state. So you can change by

```
const state = useContext(Store) || [];
```

I dont know what "useContext(..)" is suppose to return, but at least it correct the error when you have an empty array